# How to create database in Microsoft SQL Server using linq2db by code first approach in .NET CORE 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core-2.2, linq2db

Created new project in .net core 2.2 and installed nuget package **linq2db.sqlserver** using this package i am able to do CRUD with database first approach but i need to know how to do CRUD using code first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Linq2Db has a link https://linq2db.github.io/index.html
which provides more information about how to create a POCO and create a table based on it.

As per the page, a simple POCO can go like this:

```
using System;
using LinqToDB.Mapping;

[Table(Name = "Products")]
public class Product
{
  [PrimaryKey, Identity]
  public int ProductID { get; set; }

  [Column(Name = "ProductName"), NotNull]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  // ... other columns ...
}
```

Then you need to configure the connection strings.

Comment: Referring the above given link I got to know which configurations to do, but it does not cleared that how the database and tables gets created based on code.
How can I generate Database and tables based on my code